# Slicing data set for plotting

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, slice, python-xarray

I'm getting all nans and the following error message when I try to take a slice of my data for a plot: f"invalid indexer array, does not have integer dtype: {k!r}"

My data set includes monthly values, from the year 2000 to 2015 and I'd like to take the monthly data only from 2005.

The code I'm using is:

```
k = temp.sel({'time':slice('2005')})
temp_seasonal=temp[k,0,276,275].groupby('time.month')

Katrina=plt.plot(temp_seasonal) #choose the last time (-1), the surface(0), and some rando indices for lat/lon
plt.ylabel(r'$\theta$ ($\degree$C)')
plt.xlabel('Time (month)')
plt.xlim(0,11)
plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(0,12))
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(['J','F','M','A','M','J','J','A','S','O','N','D'])
plt.title(r'Seasonal cycle of $\theta$ ($\degree$C) near Center of Major Hurricane Katrina');
plt.savefig("Katrina.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

All code except the slicing of the years works, becuase I get a plot of average monthly temperatures just fine using the following code:

```
temp_seasonal=temp[:,0,276,275].groupby('time.month').mean('time')

Katrina=plt.plot(temp_seasonal) #choose the last time (-1), the surface(0), and some rando indices for lat/lon
plt.ylabel(r'$\theta$ ($\degree$C)')
plt.xlabel('Time (month)')
plt.xlim(0,11)
plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(0,12))
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(['J','F','M','A','M','J','J','A','S','O','N','D'])
plt.title(r'Seasonal cycle of $\theta$ ($\degree$C) near Center of Major Hurricane Katrina');
plt.savefig("Katrina.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, immediately after posting I figured it out! I needed to remove my slicing line and change that second line to reflect the indices for month 48-60 in my data set:

```
temp_seasonal=temp[48:60,0,276,275].groupby('time.month').mean('time')
```